# KubeDNS not injecting nameservers, Kubernetes 1.5.2 on RHEL 7-

Tags: dns, kubernetes, kube-dns

I've created a cluster with a master and 5 nodes with flannel for the POD network and that is working fine.

What is not working is that after installing kubeDNS (kubedns, dnsmasq and sidecar) but I can't get the new nameserver to be injected into HOST /etc/resolv.conf, because of that I can't resolve any hostnames.

Everything else works fine, all KubeDNS containers are running and with no errors

My kube-proxy ARGS

```
KUBE_PROXY_ARGS="--cluster-cidr=10.254.0.0/16"
```

My Kubelet configs

```
KUBELET_DNS="--cluster-dns=10.254.0.253"
KUBELET_DOMAIN="--cluster-domain=cluster.local"
```

Here are my configs for the DNS POD:

```
{
  "kind": "Pod",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kube-dns-4073989832-f7g5g",
    "generateName": "kube-dns-4073989832-",
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-dns-4073989832-f7g5g",
    "uid": "6f76055c-5b1e-11e7-b0c5-0050568fc023",
    "resourceVersion": "3974782",
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-06-27T09:53:13Z",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "kube-dns",
      "pod-template-hash": "4073989832"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "kubernetes.io/created-by": "{\"kind\":\"SerializedReference\",\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"reference\":{\"kind\":\"ReplicaSet\",\"namespace\":\"kube-system\",\"name\":\"kube-dns-4073989832\",\"uid\":\"8afa7fce-5a9e-11e7-b714-0050568fc023\",\"apiVersion\":\"extensions\",\"resourceVersion\":\"3974404\"}}\n",
      "scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod": ""
    },
    "ownerReferences": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
        "kind": "ReplicaSet",
        "name": "kube-dns-4073989832",
        "uid": "8afa7fce-5a9e-11e7-b714-0050568fc023",
        "controller": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "kube-dns-config",
        "configMap": {
          "name": "kube-dns",
          "defaultMode": 420
        }
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "kubedns",
        "image": "vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.2",
        "args": [
          "--domain=cluster.local",
          "--dns-port=10053",
          "--config-dir=/kube-dns-config",
          "--kube-master-url=http://10.64.146.26:8080",
          "--v=2"
        ],
        "ports": [
          {
            "name": "dns-local",
            "containerPort": 10053,
            "protocol": "UDP"
          },
          {
            "name": "dns-tcp-local",
            "containerPort": 10053,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          },
          {
            "name": "metrics",
            "containerPort": 10055,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "PROMETHEUS_PORT",
            "value": "10055"
          }
        ],
        "resources": {
          "limits": {
            "memory": "170Mi"
          },
          "requests": {
            "cpu": "100m",
            "memory": "70Mi"
          }
        },
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "kube-dns-config",
            "mountPath": "/kube-dns-config"
          }
        ],
        "livenessProbe": {
          "httpGet": {
            "path": "/healthcheck/kubedns",
            "port": 10054,
            "scheme": "HTTP"
          },
          "initialDelaySeconds": 60,
          "timeoutSeconds": 5,
          "periodSeconds": 10,
          "successThreshold": 1,
          "failureThreshold": 5
        },
        "readinessProbe": {
          "httpGet": {
            "path": "/readiness",
            "port": 8081,
            "scheme": "HTTP"
          },
          "initialDelaySeconds": 3,
          "timeoutSeconds": 5,
          "periodSeconds": 10,
          "successThreshold": 1,
          "failureThreshold": 3
        },
        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
      },
      {
        "name": "dnsmasq",
        "image": "vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64:1.14.2",
        "args": [
          "-v=2",
          "-logtostderr",
          "-configDir=/etc/k8s/dns/dnsmasq-nanny",
          "-restartDnsmasq=true",
          "--",
          "-k",
          "--cache-size=1000",
          "--log-facility=-",
          "--server=/cluster.local/127.0.0.1#10053",
          "--server=/in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053",
          "--server=/ip6.arpa/127.0.0.1#10053"
        ],
        "ports": [
          {
            "name": "dns",
            "containerPort": 53,
            "protocol": "UDP"
          },
          {
            "name": "dns-tcp",
            "containerPort": 53,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "resources": {
          "requests": {
            "cpu": "150m",
            "memory": "20Mi"
          }
        },
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "kube-dns-config",
            "mountPath": "/etc/k8s/dns/dnsmasq-nanny"
          }
        ],
        "livenessProbe": {
          "httpGet": {
            "path": "/healthcheck/dnsmasq",
            "port": 10054,
            "scheme": "HTTP"
          },
          "initialDelaySeconds": 60,
          "timeoutSeconds": 5,
          "periodSeconds": 10,
          "successThreshold": 1,
          "failureThreshold": 5
        },
        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
      },
      {
        "name": "sidecar",
        "image": "vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64:1.14.2",
        "args": [
          "--v=2",
          "--logtostderr",
          "--probe=kubedns,127.0.0.1:10053,kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,5,A",
          "--probe=dnsmasq,127.0.0.1:53,kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local,5,A"
        ],
        "ports": [
          {
            "name": "metrics",
            "containerPort": 10054,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "resources": {
          "requests": {
            "cpu": "10m",
            "memory": "20Mi"
          }
        },
        "livenessProbe": {
          "httpGet": {
            "path": "/metrics",
            "port": 10054,
            "scheme": "HTTP"
          },
          "initialDelaySeconds": 60,
          "timeoutSeconds": 5,
          "periodSeconds": 10,
          "successThreshold": 1,
          "failureThreshold": 5
        },
        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
      }
    ],
    "restartPolicy": "Always",
    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
    "dnsPolicy": "Default",
    "serviceAccountName": "kube-dns",
    "serviceAccount": "kube-dns",
    "nodeName": "gopher01",
    "securityContext": {}
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Running",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Initialized",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2017-06-27T09:52:45Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "Ready",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2017-06-27T09:52:55Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "PodScheduled",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2017-06-27T09:53:13Z"
      }
    ],
    "hostIP": "10.64.146.24",
    "podIP": "172.30.18.4",
    "startTime": "2017-06-27T09:52:45Z",
    "containerStatuses": [
      {
        "name": "dnsmasq",
        "state": {
          "running": {
            "startedAt": "2017-06-27T09:52:47Z"
          }
        },
        "lastState": {},
        "ready": true,
        "restartCount": 0,
        "image": "vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64:1.14.2",
        "imageID": "docker-pullable://vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny-amd64@sha256:5a9dda0fdf5bf548eb6a63260c3f5e6f5cdc3d0917279e38a435c00967c6c57c",
        "containerID": "docker://682fa7e0ffb28f26aee97a8ac7fe564096ece3ef3d7fe14fd9ed6857526d2d2f"
      },
      {
        "name": "kubedns",
        "state": {
          "running": {
            "startedAt": "2017-06-27T09:52:47Z"
          }
        },
        "lastState": {},
        "ready": true,
        "restartCount": 0,
        "image": "vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64:1.14.2",
        "imageID": "docker-pullable://vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-kube-dns-amd64@sha256:c78ed83587e42e7fc21f07756364c568c5c0fe10289f4f7f19d03a97f15b7a60",
        "containerID": "docker://20b729004655a43efd384f8dded1f97d898a3b54092e190aba3d2031e72da056"
      },
      {
        "name": "sidecar",
        "state": {
          "running": {
            "startedAt": "2017-06-27T09:52:47Z"
          }
        },
        "lastState": {},
        "ready": true,
        "restartCount": 0,
        "image": "vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64:1.14.2",
        "imageID": "docker-pullable://vvcelparti01:443/k8s-dns-sidecar-amd64@sha256:8d8c0e03e5f91ae85be7402ac88f804c52431dac32491c7a2557fd462fd2695b",
        "containerID": "docker://bbaec6e9d0aa933daaee7c33b6d64d0f37f1a57213fabd2aa1c686c61a356f7f"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my throubleshooting session:

```
$ kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system
NAME                   CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns               10.254.0.253    <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   24d
kubernetes-dashboard   10.254.170.86   <none>        80/TCP          29d
$ kubectl get ep kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
NAME       ENDPOINTS                       AGE
kube-dns   172.30.18.4:53,172.30.18.4:53   24d
```

Comment: Kubernetes documentation describes how to [Debug DNS issues](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#how-do-i-test-if-it-is-working)

In particular, [Check the local DNS configuration first](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#troubleshooting-tips)

Comment: Oh I did already check both links, nothing seams to help me to have my nameservers injected into resolv.conf

Comment: Shouldn't id be adding it to my resolv.conf or should I add it manually?